# Converting Column in Dataframe to Int

Tags: python, pandas

Here is some sample data that I've been working with; this is the second column in my dataframe:

```
OMSID
206923768
301000459
301000460
```

Here's the code snippet that I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pathName = 'pathName' #Pathname for File goes here, will change when uploaded to different machine
export = pd.read_csv(pathName, skiprows = [0], header = None, dtype =dict(OMSID=np.int64))
    #pathName: Find the correct path for the file
    #skiprows: The first row is occupied for the title, we dont need that
omsList = export.values.T[1].tolist() #Transpose the matrix + get second column
print(omsList)
```

So I figured if I converted to int then I would get something like
`[206923768, 301000459, 301000460, 206923771, 206923752, 206923755....]`

but instead I am getting
`[206923768.0, 301000459.0, 301000460.0, 206923771.0, 206923752.0, 206923755.0, 301000454.0...]`

Comment: Because your int column contains NAs. [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) then has to unwantedly coerce the int dtype to float. **Better is to use [`df.fillna(..., downcast)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to get the dtype coerced back to int.** and for all columns. `fillna()` has various useful options you can use to specify behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the data type dictionary looks strange. Try replacing
`dtype =dict(OMSID=np.int64)` with `dtype=dict('OMSID': np.int64)`.

Comment: I was using pycharm and it threw out the recommendation so I assumed it was right but realized it was kind of unreadable. Thank you for the answer but I did end up finding a solution, I'll post the answer

Comment: @chrisHG: if PyCharm is making garbage code autosuggestions, please [file a bug on it with JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html)

Comment: @smci thanks for letting me know, just filed the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Found a soltuion, I ended up just converting NANs to 0 then converting to int

```
export = pd.read_csv(pathName, skiprows = [0], header = None)
export[1] = export[1].fillna(0).astype(int)
    #pathName: Find the correct path for the file
    #skiprows: The first row is occupied for the title, we dont need that
omsList = export.values.T[1].tolist() #Transpose the matrix + get second path
print(omsList)
```